# Converting EPOCH time as a usable date for comparing to current datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, epoch

Data value example, column `[last_run]` value 1647644503000000000

```
SELECT
    CAST(DATEADD(s, (last_run / 1000000000) - 18000, '19700101') AS DATETIME2) AS 'Last_Backup'
```

This converts it properly to `Last_Backup = 2022-03-18 18:01:43.0000000`

When I try to add this query

```
, DATEDIFF(DAY, 'Last_Backup', GETDATE()) AS 'DateDifference'
```

I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, `'Last_Backup'` isn't a date and time value, it's a literal string.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They only work when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'value'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'value'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'value'`. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Also, however, you *cannot* reference a column by its alias in the same `SELECT`; you would have to repeat the expression, or use a derived table/CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the most efficient, you could always just repeat the computation like this:

```
SELECT
    CAST(DATEADD(s, (last_run / 1000000000) - 18000, '19700101') AS DATETIME2) AS 'Last_Backup',
    DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(DATEADD(s, (last_run / 1000000000) - 18000, '19700101') AS DATETIME2), GETDATE()) AS 'DateDifference'
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me, there only about 85 rows so it is still super quick.